# Git and Xcode - 1 repo with 2 branches and 2 app names

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have an ios app repo'd using git. What I'd like is to have the master branch install as App_1 and beta branch install as App_2. So that when installed from the beta branch it does not overwrite the installation from the master branch.

What I can achieve:
I can make a second branch, change the application name, build, etc. This can be achieved using these steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html). After I do this, and change the bundle identifier (com.us.my_app => com.us.my_app.beta) everything works. The beta branch installs as an entirely new app.

The problem:
When I go to checkout my master branch (I'm using terminal by the way) Xcode complains that my_app.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it's missing it's project.pbxproj file.

I thought at first that this may be due to my gitignore file, but after looking at it I don't think it is... but maybe I'm missing something... here is my gitignore for reference:

```
    *.xcuserstate
    xcuserdata/
    .DS_Store
    my_app/.DS_Store
```

EDIT: More info - here is the commit when I change nothing but the app name:

```
[testing 24f9270] testing commit
 7 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
 rename "apps/my_app\316\262-Info.plist" => apps/my_app_beta-Info.plist (97%)
 rename "apps/my_app\316\262-Prefix.pch" => apps/my_app_beta-Prefix.pch (100%)
 rename "my_app\316\262.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" => my_app_beta.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj (99%)
 rename "my_app\316\262.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata" => my_app_beta.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata (69%)
 rename "my_app\316\262.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app(\316\262).xccheckout" => "my_app_beta.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app(\316\262).xccheckout" (100%)
 rename "my_app\316\262.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app.xccheckout" => my_app_beta.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app.xccheckout (100%)
 rename "my_app\316\262.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app\316\262.xccheckout" => "my_app_beta.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/my_app\316\262.xccheckout" (100%)
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? Have a solution? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you look at the commit above, it's weird because you see that 262-Info.plist became my_app_beta-Info.plist, but what the heck is 262-Info.plist? Shouldn't this be: `my_app-Info.plist => my_app_beta.Info.plist` ? It's like the file it's changing from is gone before it can change it's name? I also notice, if I take a look in the file directory that both project files exist when I try to checkout master: my_app.xcodeproj and my_app_beta.xcodeproj can both be found in the main app folder.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this doesn't really answer the original question, but it serves as a solution for what led me to the problem in the first place. All I needed to do was add a second Target to the original project, not maintain an entirely separate branch. [Here](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/) is a tutorial on how to do this, it's a bit out dated but the idea is still there.